# Testing if await operator will succeeed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Is there any functionality in the `await/async` environment to test if `await` will suspend the method/block or not?  Or is no such functionality included in this pattern?

Comment: It depends on what you're awaiting. If it's a `Task`, you can just check whether it's already completed. You can call `GetAwaiter` and check that, but it's at least *feasible* that two calls to `GetAwaiter()` will return different results.

Comment: @Conrad: I can't think of a scenario where this information would be useful. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @StephenCleary I want to be able to execute some code only as long as an async method has not yet returned, but no longer. Such as a progress bar, but could be other low-priority tasks.

Comment: @Conrad for that look in to class like [NotifyTaskCompletion](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/NotifyTaskCompletion.cs), you can get `INotifyPropertyChanged` events fired when the tasks complet and you can hide your bar then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `IsCompleted` on the `Task` to see if it has completed yet (if it has, the method will not be suspended).  But while you can reliably determine that no continuation is necessary, you can never reliably determine that it *is* necessary, simply because the instant after you check if the `Task` is completed and see that it's not done yet, it could finish, resulting in the method not returning to the caller (yet).

Comment: This only deals with `Task` of course - there are non-task awaitables...

Comment: @JonSkeet Technically, yes, in practice, one almost never comes across anything else, so I didn't consider it worth mentioning.  Considering that it's not really a useful practice even if you *do* have a `Task`, because of the race condition, trying to write the more robust reflection code to see if there's a suitable `IsCompleted` method on a non-`Task` type seems unlikely to be useful in this context.

Comment: @Servy you don't need any reflection code, just call `GetAwaiter()` on the awaitable object and it is guaranteed to have a `IsCompleted` property, just check that one instead of the one on the task.

Answer (score 2):

For something to be awaitable it must have a function called `GetAwaiter()` and the object that is returned must [follow a specific pattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/). One of the parts of the pattern is it must have a public property `bool IsCompleted { get; }`.

```
var awaiter = foo.GetAwaiter();
if(awaiter.IsCompleted)
{
    //You know for sure awaiting foo will not cause a context change
}
else
{
    //Awaiting will likely cause a context change but the value of IsCompleted 
    // could change between the "if" check and the await call.
}

await foo;
```

Comment: Documentation says ``GetAwaiter()`` is intended only for compiler use - have you had experience with this in user land?

Comment: Like [Stephen said in his comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686440/testing-if-await-operator-will-succeeed/40688222?noredirect=1#comment68607613_40686440), I don't see a reason user-land code would ever need to actually do this unless maybe you are doing something like writing a task scheduler, That being said, I have used `.GetAwaiter()` and it works fine.

Comment: If you look at the source for Task's awaiter that is returned from `GetAwaiter()` you can see it is just doing [`public bool IsCompleted { get { return m_task.IsCompleted; } }`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,76e60de204462f00) which is exactly what Servy's answer said to do.